# display an image from server with an output stream

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, servlets

I am trying to show an image from the server in my browser.I am following this link 
http://balusc.blogspot.in/2007/04/imageservlet.html. i must say this is pretty well written and documented. I tried this and everything is working fine.

The problem is there when i am using ajax to display this image.the whole image seems to break into some codes inside the div.

i understand that the outputstream used in the code is writing directly to the page.But is it really not possible to handle that outputstream to somehow display the image in image tag of a jsp without having to create a different servlet.

Thank you for  reading

Comment: You can't send raw data through Ajax, just send back an updated `<img>` tag as Dancrumb suggested. See also : http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?24088-Ajax-Returning-OutputStream-Image

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to request image data via AJAX and then manipulate it yourself, in order to display it. Just use an `<img>` tag!

If `/my_url` is the location of your image, then

```
<img src="/my-url" alt="Appropriate description"/>
```

would do it. NOTE: `/my-url` doesn't have to be an *actual* image. It can be any resource (including a servlet) that returns image data with the appropriate MIME type set.

If you want to create the tag dynamically, you can use your favourite library, or do it iwth native JS:

```
var oImg=document.createElement("img");
oImg.setAttribute('src', '/my-url');
oImg.setAttribute('alt', 'Appropriate description');
oImg.setAttribute('height', imgHeight);
oImg.setAttribute('width', imgWidth);
document.body.appendChild(oImg);
```

### Edit

If you want to be doing this server-side (and if so, is this really AJAX?), then you might want to look at the [data uri scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).

With this scheme, you can data directly to an image tag, without needing to provide it with an HTTP resource. To use this, you convert your outputstream to base64 and use the following:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,converted-data-stream-goes-here..." alt="Who needs HTTP?"/>
```

The `image/png` would change depending on the MIME type of your source data.

Read the linked Wikipedia page to fully understand the trade-offs here.

Comment: thanks @Dancrumb for your comment which is really informative.But i am trying to do something with the outputstream used in the servlet.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding how i achieved  a solution for it.
I referred to a new page(from the page i am submitting the form) through ajax and in the new page i used an image and through its src attribute i called the servlet method which is writing the image through its outputstream.

This way the servlet is writing my image to the new file which i can position anywhere.

Comment: thanks for this.. i can't understand why this was downvoted. I didn't know you could put a servlet endpoint as an img src!